# using ajax form inside helper method

Tags: c#, razor, asp.net-ajax, asp.net-mvc-helpers

How do you use a mvc helper method to create a ajax.beginform?

for ex:

```
@helper AjaxForm(string action, string controller, object routevalues, AjaxOptions options, params MvcHtmlString[] fields)
{
    // DOES NOT WORK
    @using(Ajax.BeginForm(action, controller, routevalues, options))
    {
        foreach (var field in inputfields)
        {
            @field
        }  
    }
}
```

I would like to use this field anywhere in my views like this

```
@helper AjaxForm("Action", "Controller", new {id = "1"}, new AjaxOptions())
```

Answer (score 0):

Like this

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{


}
```

Comment: This was not the problem i was trying to focus on. The problem is to get the real problem is to get the AjaxHelper into the method.